# Best way to get notification in from gmail in C#

Tags: c#, .net, gmail

Best way to get notification in from gmail in C#, when new email is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Gmail inbox feed](https://developers.google.com/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed). It's a bit lighter than using POP3 for this.

> The Gmail Inbox Feed will output your Inbox as an XML document. You can use an RSS aggregator to view this, or you can consume the feed with your own app.

> Note: This feed is only available for Gmail accounts on Google Workspace domains.

Comment: link has died :-(

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at 
[Gmail API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmail-api/)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look into using POP3 Libraries. If you are willing to use existing one, you can have a look at [here](http://trixy.justinkbeck.com/2009/07/c-pop3-library-with-ssl-for-gmail.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **IMAP** protocol and **IDLE** command.

Mail.dll supports this out-ot-the-box:

http://www.limilabs.com/blog/imap-idle

[Please note that this is a commercial product I created]